# How to write generic function to set token and cookies received from one GET API to test other APIs using Rest Assured

Tags: api, rest-assured, web-api-testing

Below code is working for APIs written in one test but I want to use authentication in other test classes. Please help me with that I am using JAVA

@Test(priority = 01, groups = { "API", "API Testing" }, description = "Validate ")
public void defaultAndSizeSolutionAPI() throws IOException {

```
    FileInputStream fis= new FileInputStream(new File(userDir +"payload.json"));
    
    //to get the csrf token and cookies
        Response response = RestAssured.given()
                    .headers(headers.defaultHeaders())
                    .get("https://c9w22348.itcs.hpe.com/Services/SizingEngine/Gettoken");
            
            Log.info(" API Status Code : "+ response.getStatusCode());
            Log.info("CSRF Token  : "+ response.getHeader("AfToken"));
            Log.info("Cookies  : "+ response.getCookies()); 
            
    //To set csrf Token and cookies and get ezmeralSizer Default 
    
        RestAssured.given()
            .headers(headers.defaultHeaders())
            .header("CSRFToken", response.getHeader("AfToken"))
            .cookies(response.getCookies())
            
            
            //For Solution Api (Actual Test)
        Response solution= RestAssured.given()
                    .headers(headers.defaultHeaders())
                    .header("CSRFToken",response.getHeader("AfToken"))
                    .cookies(response.getCookies())
                    .body(IOUtils.toString(fis, "UTF-8"))
                    .post("XXXXXXXXXXXXX/Endpoints");
             
                    Log.info("Solution API Status Code : "+ solution= .getStatusCode());
                Log.info("Solution response body : "+ solution= .getBody().jsonPath().prettify());
                softAssert.assertEquals(200, solution= .getStatusCode());
                softAssert.assertAll();
                
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're using TestNG, so it could be done in such way:
Make an Authorization request in method with annotation @BeforeSuite which will be executed before all the tests.
In that method extract your token value to a String for example, and the set as a property.

```
final String TOKEN_VALUE = authResponse.path("access_token").toString(); 
System.setProperty("token", TOKEN_VALUE);
```

After that, just get the property in your regular test methods.

```
given()
      .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
      .header("Authorization", System.getProperty("token"))
      .get("your/endpoint/url")
```